# NumPy precision when doing dot product

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, precision, theano

I am using Theano/NumPy doing some deep learning stuff. I found a very annoying problem. I got a weights matrix A(suppose to be 50*2048), and a feature vector b(2048 dim).

A is initialized using

```
self.alpha = np.random.random((50, 2048)).astype(np.float32) * 2 - 1.0
```

b is a 2048 dim numpy.ndarrary from theano.

The problem is

```
X = numpy.dot(A, b)
Y = [numpy.dot(A[i], b) for i in xrange(50)]
```

Some rows of X and Y are not strictly equal. I compared them and found that the difference is in 1e-6 to 1e-7.

Currently I prefer to use the second to computed the dot product since it seems that it can learn better weights. But the first is much faster. So I'm wondering why there is such a big difference. Is it caused by different implementations of dot(matrix, vector) and dot(vector, vector)? Thanks a lot!

--edit
As uhoh mentioned, this is the code that you can reproduce it.

```
import numpy as np

test_time = 1000
vector_size = 100
matrix_size = (100, 100)

for i in xrange(test_time):
    a = np.random.random(matrix_size).astype(np.float32) * 2 - 1.0
    b = np.random.random(vector_size).astype(np.float32)
    x = np.dot(a, b)
    y = [np.dot(a[i], b) for i in xrange(a.shape[0])]
    for k in xrange(len(y)):
        epsilon = x[k] - y[k]
        if abs(epsilon) > 1e-7:
            print('Diff: {0}\t{1}\t{2}'.format(x[k], y[k], epsilon))
```

Comment: Can you duplicate the problem with a smaller array of numbers that you can include in your question? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Sometimes by isolating the phenomenon you can find the issue yourself in the process.

Comment: I can replicate the problem with any array size...

Comment: Why there is a difference, I don't know. Why is it so big is due to you using float32. Leave it float64 (I know it is not compatible with theano GPU usage) and the difference drops to e-14/-15.

Comment: @JulienBernu float32 is faster. And even I leave it float64, the weights it learned are still different.

Comment: @uhoh I posted the code that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser sorry about this stupid mistake...

Comment: Nonrandom example: `x = np.ones((2, 100), dtype=np.float32)/100; y = np.ones(100, dtype=np.float32)`.  Compare `np.dot(x, y)[0]` and `np.dot(x[0], y)`.

Comment: That's a nice "minimal" example @WarrenWeckesser. So it looks like this is just an amplification of the inevitable precision or round-off errors that happen when we express numbers in a computer. The reason it looks so big is that the summation of the dot product amplifies it.

Comment: The comment by @JulienBernu closes the case. With more precision, the effect gets that much smaller. Then Warren's example gives `A=1.0000000000000004` and `B=0.99999999999999989`. It's that summing in the dot product that makes it *seem* so big - just the cost of doing business using float32. The difference in Warren's example is ~1E-7. If you make he array 100 times longer it's ~1E-3 - which I **don't** understand!

Comment: Apparently `dot` follows different code paths depending on whether the first argument is 1D or 2D, and the different paths result in slightly different numerical errors.

Comment: FWIW if you are doing "deep learning stuff", stop worrying about errors on this scale immediately ...

Answer (score 2):

Well there is usually a trade-off between performance and precision. You may have to compensate one in favor or the other. Although I personally do not believe a difference of 0.0000001 is a big deal in most applications.  If you seek higher precision you'd better go with `float64`, but note that `float64` operations are extremely slow on the GPUs, especially NVIDIA 9xx series GPUs.

I may note that the mentioned issue seems to depend on your hardware settings too cause I do not encounter such problem on my machine.

You may also use `np.allclose(x, y)` to see if the difference is tangible.